# Possible conflict when linking with two versions of libgfortran at the same time?

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

Is it safe to link with both `libgfortran.3.0.0` and `libgfortran.1.0.0`, or does these libraries conflict each other?

## Edit 0: some more info to answer the comments

My context is building packages with the conda package manager.

I would like to build the packages using the [gcc 4.8.5](http://anaconda.org/asmeurer/gcc) conda package. This `gcc` has been build on `centos 5` (with this [recipe](https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/tree/master/gcc-4.8)) so it depends on a `glibc` version compatible with most GNU/Linux distrib. It depends on `libgfortran.3.0.0`. I want to use it to build the packages, and to let users use it to link libraries provides by the packages I've build.

I would also like to link the packages with [openblas 0.2.14](https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/), which depends on `libgfortran.1.0.0`. A solution would be to rebuild `openblas` with `gcc 4.8.5`, but the problem would remain for other conda packages that depend on this `openblas` (like `numpy`).

I just tried to build `scalpack` using these conda packages`gcc 4.8.5` and `openblas 0.2.14`, and then compile an [example](http://acts.nersc.gov/scalapack/hands-on/etc/pdpttr_2/pdpttr_2.f.html).

I get an error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libgfortran.so.1, needed by /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libopenblas.so, may conflict with libgfortran.so.3
```

The execution of the executable seems correct.

## Edit 1

On the resulting executable,

```
$ objdump -x main | grep gfortran
      NEEDED      libgfortran.so.3
      required from libgfortran.so.3:
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000005              _gfortran_transfer_integer_write@@GFORTRAN_1.4
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000005              _gfortran_transfer_character_write@@GFORTRAN_1.4
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  000000000000003f              _gfortran_stop_string@@GFORTRAN_1.0
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  00000000000000d0              _gfortran_runtime_error@@GFORTRAN_1.0
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  00000000000000d0              _gfortran_runtime_error_at@@GFORTRAN_1.0
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000015              _gfortran_set_args@@GFORTRAN_1.0
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000014              _gfortran_st_write@@GFORTRAN_1.0
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000078              _gfortran_os_error@@GFORTRAN_1.0
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000139              _gfortran_set_options@@GFORTRAN_1.0
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  0000000000000005              _gfortran_transfer_array_write@@GFORTRAN_1.4
    0000000000000000       F *UND*  00000000000000ae              _gfortran_st_write_done@@GFORTRAN_1.0
```

and

```
$ ldd main

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdf5a2000)
libopenblas.so.0 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00002b0e7cf62000)
libmpi_usempi.so.1 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libmpi_usempi.so.1 (0x00002b0e7ddc9000)
libmpi_mpifh.so.2 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.2 (0x00002b0e7dfcc000)
libmpi.so.1 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libmpi.so.1 (0x00002b0e7e223000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00002b0e7e71b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003b15c00000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b0e7ea4b000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00002b0e7ec61000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003b14c00000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003b14400000)
libgfortran.so.1 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/./libgfortran.so.1 (0x00002b0e7ee9e000)
libopen-rte.so.7 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/./libopen-rte.so.7 (0x00002b0e7f136000)
libopen-pal.so.6 => /home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/sca/lib/./libopen-pal.so.6 (0x00002b0e7f42d000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003b14800000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003b15000000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003b17400000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003b14000000)
```

Comment: Why would you do that? They may very well conflict due to duplicated symbols. Did you try it? It is normal to link to different libgfortran from a slightly different compiler version, but what you propose is very weird.

Comment: I don't have the 1.0.0 version around to check, but those almost assuredly will conflict due to symbol names if they are unversioned.  Have you tried linking to both at once?  what happened?

Comment: symbols are versioned since [gfortran 4.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News#gfortran_4.3), but i don't know which gfortran version the libgfortran.so.1.0.0 come from

Comment: I just stumbled upon this same issue @DavidFroger, any news? Do you think this is an anaconda bug?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to have gcc and gfortran packaged in conda, but I still have difficuties to use the gcc conda package (http://ipscc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/package-details.html#glibc-and-gcc-versions). Currently, the conda packages I build requires gfortran installed in the system (http://ipscc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html). So I link with both libgfortran 1.0.0 and 3.0.0, and did not encounter problems. Hope it helps...

Comment: I mean, I think the best solution would be to rebuild every conda packages with gcc and gfortran packaged in conda, so only libgfortran 3.0.0 is used.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'm having lots of problems trying to compile FEniCS too, hope we can solve them with some effort.